# Why Inside the docker container the outbound connection (on any port) is just hanging?

Tags: docker, connection

On the VPN host , outbound connections are working. For example, it can access port 10051 on pod
root@host# curl ip:10051
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Inside the docker container the outbound connection (on any port) is just hanging
Anyone has any idea

Comment: So If I understand correctly you are running VPN on host and after running VPN, outgoing connections from docker containers don't work?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes you are wright. You have similar issue in the past?

Comment: Check `/etc/resolv.conf` on host after connecting to VPN, and then use the same inside docker and see if it works